# No repository found for Egit upgrade in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, egit, p2

Where is the latest Egit p2 repositories? I'm using Oxygen .2 and I get these following errors after trying to check for software updates.

```
!ENTRY org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 4 4 2018-01-18 14:17:43.037
!MESSAGE An error occurred while collecting items to be installed
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.engine 4 0 2018-01-18 14:17:43.037
!MESSAGE session context was:(profile=_home_isheedm_bin_jee-latest-released_eclipse, phase=org.eclipse.equinox.internal.p2.engine.phases.Collect, operand=, action=).
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2018-01-18 14:17:43.037
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit,4.11.0.201801172130
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2018-01-18 14:17:43.037
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.core,4.11.0.201801172130
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2018-01-18 14:17:43.037
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.doc,4.11.0.201801172130
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2018-01-18 14:17:43.037
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.gitflow,4.11.0.201801172130
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2018-01-18 14:17:43.037
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.gitflow.ui,4.11.0.201801172130
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2018-01-18 14:17:43.037
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.mylyn.ui,4.11.0.201801172130
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2018-01-18 14:17:43.037
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit.ui,4.11.0.201801172130
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2018-01-18 14:17:43.038
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jgit,4.11.0.201801171708
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2018-01-18 14:17:43.038
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.jgit.archive,4.11.0.201801171659
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2018-01-18 14:17:43.038
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,com.jcraft.jzlib,1.1.1.v201205102305
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2018-01-18 14:17:43.038
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.egit,4.11.0.201801172130
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2018-01-18 14:17:43.038
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.egit.gitflow.feature,4.11.0.201801172130
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2018-01-18 14:17:43.038
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.egit.mylyn,4.11.0.201801172130
!SUBENTRY 1 org.eclipse.equinox.p2.artifact.repository 4 0 2018-01-18 14:17:43.038
!MESSAGE No repository found containing: org.eclipse.update.feature,org.eclipse.jgit,4.11.0.201801171711
```

Answer (score 6):

The problem definitely lies in the protocol. Change all the download.eclipse.org/* update sites from http to **https** protocol and the problem will be resolved.
The same solution is valid for other Eclipse plugins too.

Answer (score 4):

maybe the problem is that "http://" can't get the the repository, but "https://" can.

My repository url with problem is "http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-nightly/".

When I ran "Help -> check for Updates" it can get the upgradable package list, but when I confirmed to download and upgrade them, it would get an error says "No repository found containing: osgi.bundle,org.eclipse.egit,5.3.0.201901221321" and so on.
After I changed the repository url in the setting "Available Software Site" from "http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-nightly/" to "http**s**://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-nightly/", the problem solved.

Answer (score 3):

Found the answer myself, but I wanted to document how I did it.

There are at least 3 update URLs I found:

- http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates/ (4.10.0.201712302008-r)
- http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-stable-nightly/ (4.10.1.201712311822)
- http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates-nightly/?d (4.11.0.201801172130)

I'm not trying to live on the bleeding edge of development, just trying to keep Eclipse happy. The version matched the updates-nightly URL. I removed that URL from my list of sites (Help > Install New Software > Manage, delete "updates-nightly" URL).

I then ran the Help > Check for Updates menu again, and it found the first "updates" URL version (4.10.0.201712302008-r), then updated it OK.

Comment: I just had the same error message but didn't have the nightly URL's listed. I removed the existing http://download.eclipse.org/egit/updates/ URL, closed the subsequent windows, re-ran "Check for Updates" and got the "all good" message. Re-added the URL fresh and repeated steps. Got the update as requested without error.